# Javascript RegEx to find first line of each paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex

This is probably a simple one but I'm very much a regex novice.

I'm looking to select the first line of every paragraph within a textarea on a page using a regular expression. After thinking I was there I have hit a problem.

Using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ I came up with this:

```
/\r\r.*\r/g
```

but then I place that into my javascript and ran it on the page:

```
var headingsArr = document.getElementById("text").value.match(/\r\r.*\r/g);
```

and the array returns null.

Have I got the regular expression right and if so where am I going wrong when using it in my javascript!?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what your newline characters are. I think you may better go for

```
/(?:\r\n|[\r\n]){2}.*(?:\r\n|[\r\n])/g
```

I know in Regexr only a `\r` is a newline. But in Windows normally `\r\n` is used, but under .*ix its normally only the `\n`.

So `(?:\r\n|[\r\n])` is an alternation, it tries at first to match `\r\n` if this is not found it matches either `\r` or `\n`.

Comment: BRILLIANT.... After the day I've had I wish I could mark this up 1000 times! - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of future searchers, if you just need to style the first line of text, you can use the css pseudoclass ::first-line :

```
textarea::first-line { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp